# Putty - Share a SSH Tunnel to other computers on LAN?

Tags: ssh

I have a Windows workstation that has established an SSH connection to a remote server using Putty. From that workstation, I can tunnel stuff through the SSH tunnel, including a HTTP proxy that is running on the SSH server

I'm wondering, is it possible to enable other computers in the same subnet as the workstation to connection to that workstation, and use its SSH tunnel/HTTP proxy?

I tried using the "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" option in Putty, but I still get a connection refused when I try to connect from other boxes to the Windows workstations.

What is the proper way to configure this, so that I can share the HTTP proxy via SSH tunnel?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dependend which settings you used for the tunnels.

Forget the crap which I wrote. Go with settings like these but point the destination to the proxy server like you already did before I told you otherwise.

[image: tunnel settings]

After initiating the tunnel use `netstat -a` and look if the port is openend correctly under the address `0.0.0.0`.

```
$ netstat -a | find "3025"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3025           pacey-PC:0            ABHÖREN
  TCP    [::]:3025              pacey-PC:0            ABHÖREN
```

You can also check the eventlog in the putty menu.

Comment: That's actually what I've set - "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" is set to on, source port is set to 22, destination is set to "x.x.x.x:22" (my LAN IP). When I try to netcat on port 22 to this box from another box, I get "port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused".

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. Depending on which version of windows you are on you might have an active Windows Firewall.

Comment: Ok, I seem to be through when I set it to source port 22, destination set to "hostname.com:22". However, using destination "localhost:22" doesn't seem to work. Any idea why that is, or the difference between them? I thought localhost in that context *was* the SSH server? Also, Komodo IDE, using Open Remote Files to SSH server localhost (via the Putty tunnel) works if it's set to localhost, but not hostname (i.e. the opposite). Kinda annoying, I have to swap back/forth...any idea why?

Comment: Can you set this via the command line? I run it like this `putty.exe -ssh -v -i key.ppk -D 9853 admin@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

[corrected based on below comment]

telnet to the forwarded port from local machine and then from remote machine. If you are able to connect using local machine (where putty is running) and not from other machine then it is firewall issue or SSH client is listening only on local port and not on 0.0.0.0 for incoming connections.

Comment: SSH clients typically have a flag that specifies whether other machines on the network are allowed to connect to the forwarded port.  So even without firewalling this may not work.